# C/Linux: How to equally assign computations to threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have to calculate how many times the '1' digit occurs in numbers from 1 to N. For example for 11 the output is 4, because 1 is found once in "1", once in "10" and twice in "11". If my N is 1.000.000 for example (but a bigger N would make a better example), and i give it 4 threads (i will give at first the same number of entries to each thread), my first thread will compute the numbers from 1 to 250.000. but from 0 to 9 it does one computation to found '1', from 10-99 it does two computations to find '1', from 100-999 it does three, and so on, so the first thread will finish faster then the other (the other threads will have a constant number 6 of computations for each entry). What strategy can I apply to my program on order for every thread to have approximately the same execution time, no matter how big is the N. 
 
This is my distribution code (the one that assigns each thread the same number of entries), and i have to change it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++){
        if(i == 0)
            info[i].from = 0;
        else
            info[i].from = info[i - 1].to + 1;

        info[i].to = info[i].from + n / threads - 1;

        if(i < n % threads)
            info[i].to++;

        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread_function, &info[i]);
    }
```

'info' is a struct that holds the range of number each thread has to compute:

```
typedef struct {
    int from;
    int to;
} th_struct;
```

Comment: Look into using OpenMP.

Comment: @Shawn i have to do this for uni, not professionally, so i need to code this myself